# Calculating the minimum and maximum values from a user-generated list

Tags: c++, loops

I am writing code for an assignment that wants me to make a program that asks the user for the amount of integers they'd like to input then it accepts each input while testing if the value is the max value or the minimum.

The program runs fine but for some reason will stop and show me the min and max number when I have entered in 1 integer less than the original input.

---

Examples of the problem I am having:

- If I input 5 for the first value, it asks me to enter 5 integers.
- After entering 4 numbers, 1 2 3 and 4.
- It tells me the max is 4 and min is 1.
- It prevents me from entering in the 5th integer.

Additionally,

- If I input 5 for the first value, it asks me to enter 5 integers.
- If I enter a negative number, like -1, the input allowed to me is further
  shortened.
- If I enter -1, 2, 3 then the output is min: 2 and max: 3

---

I have two main questions:

1. What adjustments do I need to make to my code so that I can properly
   enter in the number of integers initially asked for?
2. What adjustments need to be made in order for me to be able to enter
   negative integers so they are outputted correctly?

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input;
    int tmp;
    int counter = 1;
    int max_num = 0;
    int min_num;

    // prompt user for integer amount
    cout << "How many integers would you like to enter? " << endl;
    cin >> input;

    cout << "Please enter " << input << " integers." << endl;

    tmp = input;

    // loop for requested amount with a test for each input
    while (counter <= tmp) {
        cin >> input;

        // if smaller than previous number it is the minimum
        if (input < min_num || min_num == -1) {
            min_num = input;
            counter++;
        }

        // if larger than previous number it becomes max number else
        if (input > max_num) {
            max_num = input;
            counter++;
        } else { // continue loop if number isn't bigger than max or smaller than min
            counter++;
        }
    }

    // display the max and min
    cout << "min: " << min_num << endl;
    cout << "max: " << max_num << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing uninitialized variable `min_num`

Comment: Simply use your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, paying attention to when and where `counter` gets incremented, ***and why***. Problem solved. You should be able to figure out the bug in your code all by yourself. This is what a debugger is for. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: Think about how many times you want `counter` to be incremented. If you have a new minimum, then `counter` might be incremented twice! This'll cause you to enter less than `tmp` numbers. You should only be incrementing once, at the end of the loop.

Comment: *What adjustments do I need to make to my code* -- Sorry, but this is part of programming -- fixing your own bugs.  It's not as if programs are supposed to run correctly the first time, and anything wrong is an anomaly that requires a post on StackOverflow.  Having bugs and fixing them is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.

Comment: I'm asking on StackOverflow because I have learning C++ for 2 weeks and thought it was a resource to ask experienced coders what I may be doing wrong. I have been trying to find an answer on my own but can't figure this out.. 

I'll try to remove some counters so it doesn't increment more than one time. I appreciate the pointers. 

What do you mean that min_num is uninitialized? Should I make it min_num = 0 to initialize? or another integer? @IgorTandetnik

Comment: @UnknownObject Local variables must be initialized. Think about what a sensible starting minimum value would be. What if the lowest number that the user enters is a 1? Then a 0 wouldn't work, because then a 1 wouldn't be the output.

Comment: @APerson wouldn't the most sensible value be an initial variable with no value attached? The first value is the min and the max. The second becomes the min or the max, so on and so forth. 

I don't know how to codify that into C++ language though. I don't know where to start to look.

Comment: @UnknownObject Do you read your [compiler warnings carefully](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff251a9e33d293c9)?

Comment: @APerson *wouldn't the most sensible value be an initial variable with no value attached?* -- C++ doesn't work this way.  An uninitialized variable can have any garbage in it.  It could be 0, 1, -231, 4232453, you don't know.  That's why you give your variable an initial value before starting to use it.  Your `min_num` is being used starting out a trash value, and you're using it in the `if` statement.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay that makes sense. Wouldn't it make the most sense to make 'min_num = 0' and remove it from my 'if' statement?

Comment: note that in one iteration of your `while` loop, `counter` might be incremented by two. a `for` loop would make everything much easier imho

Comment: changing it to a for loop fixed the issue i was having. thank you!!